# peer to multi-peer interprocess communication

Tags: windows, ipc

What is the best method for peer to multi-peer interprocess communication in windows.
( One application will send interrupts to many listeners )
One method comes to my mind is to use SendMessage with the HWND_BROADCAST parameter.
What else I can do?

Answer (score -1):

UPD, TCP/IP, Shared Memory, named pipes, etc.

Comment: Thats just listing IPC methods - and isn't particularly useful for answering the question.